# Display animated GIF in ASP.NET page while executing web service

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, .net-4.0

I've read many posts on this site, as well as MSDN, but can't quite find the solution I'm looking for. Here is my situation: I have a page that allows users to "upload" a file. The page includes an asp.net fileUpload control. However, all it does is send the byte array to a WSE 2.0 web service. I can't change this. This may be updated in the future, but for now, this is what I have to go with.

The page has an animated gif that starts when the user clicks the submit button. And the page should be updated accordingly based on the result returned by the web service call. I'm able to start the gif and consume the WS successfully. However, while the page is hitting the web service, the gif file freezes.

I then tried to use a separate thread to consume the web service. This speeds up the process and does not freeze the gif, but the page is not updated when the web service completes. If I put the main thread to sleep, the page updates, but I'm back to the same issue mentioned above, where the gif freezes.

I'm pretty sure I could make the call using javascript and update the page that way, but at this point, I'd really rather do it server side (out of stubbornness if nothing else).

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried to make an asynchronous call to the web service?

Comment: No, I read about it, but I'm not sure how to get the page to post back with the updated values when the service is returned.

Comment: Using call backs, you can flush some script or hide the image in the call back method. You can check "Using Callbacks" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480512.aspx

Comment: Recently I have the same problem and do you have panels?If then try to remove them and try again.

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me as well. I've managed to fix this by wrapping the `img` tag inside a `div` and just showing / hiding the `div` via JavaScript using the **setTimeout** function. The GIF won't freeze this way.

**Example:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showLoadingIco() {
        setTimeout(showLoadingGif, 50);
    }
    function showLoadingGif() {
        // Using jQuery
        $('#myDiv').css('display', 'inline');
    } 
</script>
```

Note that your HTML code must look like this:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none">
    <img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```

Comment: But this is not linked to actual time taken to complete the upload.

Comment: @mohammedn Isn't' his problem that the GIF freezes while the page is loading? If not, I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

The Upload File control doesn't work well with Update Panels, so my guess is that you're running into a full postback, which is why the image stops spinning.  If you're not using an Update Panel (or some other Ajax platform), you're almost definitely having a post back.

It's not too tough to pull off asynchronously with JQuery though.  Check out [this link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1579635.aspx/1) for an example.